# crop image with imagemagick offset given in percentage

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

imagemagick's crop command supports [cropping to a percentage of an image](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_percent) but the offset values must be specified in pixel values, e.g.:

```
convert image.png -crop 50%x+10+20
```

I want to crop with offset values `x` and `y` given in percentage of the image width, and height respectively. The pixel values can be calculated, for instance if the image size is `100x200` an offset of 10% would result in 10 and 20 respectively. Is it possible to do this calculation as part of the call to `convert`? Width and height are available as `%w` and `%h` at some places, but this does not work:

```
convert image.png -crop 50%x+(0.1*%w)+(0.1*%h)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're running IM v6 you can use FX expressions with "-set" to set image attributes. By setting the page geometry you can specify the offsets to a calculated percentage and do the crop like this...

```
convert image.png -set page -%[fx:w*0.1]-%[fx:h*0.1] -crop 50%x+0+0 result.png
```

That reads the image, sets the geometry for the upper left corner to a location outside the original canvas, and crops to the new top left corner specified by the geometry.

Note the offsets are negative numbers.

Also, if you're doing additional processing in the same command you'll probably want to "+repage" after the crop in order to reset the page geometry to the new WxH+0+0.

Edited to add: You can even include the width and height dimensions for the crop when using "-set page". This command would crop an output of 50% the input width and height, and starting at 10% in from the left and top...

```
convert image.png \
   -set page %[fx:w*0.5]x%[fx:h*0.5]-%[fx:w*0.1]-%[fx:h*0.1] -crop +0+0 result.png
```

Notice how the crop operation is simply "-crop +0+0" since the dimensions and offsets are in the page geometry.

This method lets you use more complex calculations than just using a percent or number of pixels for the cropped output dimensions.

Answer (score 3):

With v7 **ImageMagick**, make start image:

```
magick -size 200x100 gradient: a.jpg
```

Now crop using lots of calculated widths, heights, offsets:

```
magick a.jpg -crop "%[fx:w*0.9]x%[fx:h*0.8]+%[fx:w*0.1]+%[fx:h*0.05]" b.png
```

Check:

```
identify b.png
b.png PNG 180x80 200x100+20+5 8-bit Gray 256c 408B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

---

If you only have v6, use `bash` and integer arithmetic:

```
read w h < <(identify -format "%w %h" a.jpg)
convert a.jpg -crop $((w*80/100))x$((h*90/100))+$((w*10/100))+$((h*5/100))  result.png
```

Check:

```
identify result.png
result.png PNG 160x90 200x100+20+5 8-bit Gray 256c 412B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that in ImageMagick 6. But you can do that in ImageMagick 7.

```
magick image.png -crop "50%x+%[fx:0.1*w]+%[fx:0.1*h]" +repage result.png
```

In ImageMagick 6, you need to do the computations ahead of the command, store them in a variable and use the variable in the crop command.

However, in ImageMagick 6, you can do the equivalent using -distort with viewport processing as follows:

```
convert image.png -set option:distort:viewport "%[fx:0.5*w]x%[fx:0.5*h]+%[fx:0.1*w]+%[fx:0.1*h]" -filter point -distort SRT 0 result.png
```